# Trouble writing a dictionary to csv with keys as headers and values as columns

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a  dictionary that looks like:

```
mydict = {"foo":[1,2], "bar":[3,4], "asdf":[5,6]}
```

I'm trying to write this to a CSV file so that it looks like:

```
foo,bar,asdf
1,3,5
2,4,6
```

I've spend the last hour looking for solutions, and the closest one I found suggested doing something like this:

```
headers = mydict.keys()
with open("File2.csv","w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(headers)
    writer.writerows(zip(mydict.values())
```

This writes the headers ok, but not the values. Here is my output:

```
foo,bar,asdf
[1,2]
[3,4]
[5,6]
```

How do I get to the output I need? I'd really appreciate some help. Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of `zip(mydict.values())`, use `zip(*mydict.values())`.  Here is the difference:

```
>>> zip(mydict.values())
[([1, 2],), ([3, 4],), ([5, 6],)]
>>> zip(*mydict.values())
[(1, 3, 5), (2, 4, 6)]
```

Basically the second version does the same thing as `zip([1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6])`.  This is called [Unpacking Argument Lists](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) in the docs.

To enforce a sort, use the following:

```
>>> zip(*([k] + mydict[k] for k in sorted(mydict)))
[('asdf', 'bar', 'foo'), (5, 3, 1), (6, 4, 2)]
```

This includes the headers, so just pass this into `writerows()` and remove your `writerow()` call for the headers.

Of course you can provide a `key` argument to the `sorted()` function there to do any sorting you like.  For example to ensure the same order as you have in the question:

```
>>> order = {'foo': 0, 'bar': 1, 'asdf': 2}
>>> zip(*([k] + mydict[k] for k in sorted(mydict, key=order.get)))
[('foo', 'bar', 'asdf'), (1, 3, 5), (2, 4, 6)]
```

Comment: Thanks @F.J that's very helpful. I have a piggy back question for you -- how can I get sorted headers and zipped sorted values?

Comment: That's just beautiful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Also, without using `csv`:

```
mydict = {"foo":[1,2], "bar":[3,4], "asdf":[5,6]}

with open("File2.csv","w") as f:
    f.write(",".join(mydict.keys()) + "\n")
    for row in zip(*mydict.values()):
        f.write(",".join(str(n) for n in row) + "\n")
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you use tablib?

I usually use tablib for this use. Its pretty simple to use: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tablib/0.9.3

http://docs.python-tablib.org/en/latest/api/