# Python 3: writing several dictionaries to a CSV file incrementally

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I checked the topic: [Writing multiple Python dictionaries to csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22273970/writing-multiple-python-dictionaries-to-csv-file) but I think it does not answer my question yet.

I have several dictionaries like:

```
{day:1, temperature: 30}
{day:2, temperature: 40}
```

and so on

The dictionaries are not ready at once but are downloaded through a scheduler.

I want to write to a file as:

```
day temperature
1 30
2 40
```

and continue to append to the file when new dictionaries come in.

How could I do that with Python 3?

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 3):

Using the `csv` module and an iterable of dictionaries `L`:

```
import csv

L = [{'day': 1, 'temperature': 30},
     {'day': 2, 'temperature': 40}]

with open(r'c:\temp\out.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f)
    wr.writerow(['day', 'temperature'])
    for item in L:
        wr.writerow([item['day'], item['temperature']])
```

Result:

```
day,temperature
1,30
2,40
```